# Is there a workaround in Dynamodb for use case for retrieving top X items based on some attribute across the partitions?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Consider a table with two columns: `userId(partition key), score`.
No of estimated userId = 10,000. Task is to efficiently retrieve top `50` and next top `50` and so on items in pagination fashion based on `score` across all `userId`.
Is there any way to achieve this without using full table scan?\

If use case was to only show top 50 then I could have persisted some heap data structure to only keep top 50 items and retrieved from it but user can retrieve next 50 and so on items also. So this is not an option.

What If I use a dummy partition key attribute whose value remains the same and put sortkey on `score` ie. columns = `root(partition key), score(sort key), userId`.
Here value of root can remain same. Then I can just query for top scores. 
According to docs this is bad practise. Partitions should be uniformly distributed and they should have many distinct values relative to no of total items in the table. There can be performance throttling. It says if there are few hot partitions, performance can be affected due to unbalanced distribution. But is it also true if there is only and only 1 partition? Is there any configuration I am missing that can favour dynamodb table with 1 partition? Also partition size limit is 10GB. Assuming items to be 0.25KB in size, no of items can be 42949672960 which is huge as compared to no users we are estimating.

Is there any work around or configuration to achieve this or do I have no choice but to implement this type of table in Relational Database only?

Comment: "According to docs this is bad practice" -- yes, in general this is bad practice. DynamoDB is designed in a way that forces you to design your solution so that it can scale. If you're saying "sure, but I don't really need the scale, I'm only here because I like managed key-value stores" then go ahead and skip on the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Make a GSI with the partition key of "X" (or any other singular value) and the sort key the score. You can then do a Query on the partition key "X" asking for the top 50 scores. It'll be the top scores across all users. If you had millions of users you'd need to design around hot keys but with 10,000 users, you don't need to.

Send the client pages of results. For each client, remember the latest LastEvaluatedKey they've seen. That way you can start efficiently reading them the next chunk by passing the LEK in again on the next Query. It's like a bookmark.

There's no efficient way to say "Give me items 101 through 150" without starting from the front. Imagine a dictionary. I can ask you to tell me the next 50 words after "apple" but if I ask you to tell me the 101 to 150 words you're going to need to start with "a" and count so you know which is 101.

Also, partitions don't have size limits unless you're using LSIs, which is a good reason to use GSIs instead of LSIs. No limit then.